# Feeding crystal report with filtered data c#

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Im trying to pass a query as the `DataSource` for my crystal report. But rather than the report displaying the filtered data, it displays all the data in the associated tables.

This is what im doing to pass the data

Accessor

```
class cStockIssuanceSlipDetails
{
    public string itemCode { get; set; }
    public string itemDescription { get; set; }
    public double unitcost { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }

}
```

Filter

```
public DataSet Products_info(int slip_no)
    {
        string queryProducts = "SELECT p.ItemCode,p.itemDescription,p.SaleCost,slip.Quantity,slip.Amount FROM tblstockissuanceslip slip " +
        "INNER JOIN tblprowareinventory pi ON slip.inventoryID_FK = pi.inventoryID " +
        "INNER JOIN tblprowareproducts p ON pi.ItemID_FK = p.ItemID "+
        "WHERE slip.SIP_NO = ?slipno";
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryProducts,con.connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?slipno", slip_no);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            using (MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                mda.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
```

Setting the `DataSource`

```
List<cStockIssuanceSlipDetails> _List = new List<cStockIssuanceSlipDetails>();
        DataSet ds = Data.Products_info(5);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            _List.Add(new cStockIssuanceSlipDetails
            {
                itemCode = dr["itemCode"].ToString(),
                itemDescription = dr["itemDescription"].ToString(),
                unitcost = Convert.ToDouble(dr["SaleCost"]),
                quantity = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Quantity"]),
                amount = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Amount"]),
            });

        }
        rStockIssuanceSlip1.SetDataSource(_List);
```

Comment: I don't think it's ever gonna work when you set the datasource to a user-defined object collection. Did you try to set the `RecordSelectionFormula` for the report-object instead?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?

```
class cStockIssuanceSlipDetails
{
    public string itemCode { get; set; }
    public string itemDescription { get; set; }
    public double unitcost { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }

--Create a variable to store the value you want to pass in your sql statement
--use this variable to store the value before concatenating in to your sql statement
    public string topass { get; set; } 

}
Filter

public DataSet Products_info(int slip_no)
    {
        string queryProducts = "SELECT p.ItemCode,p.itemDescription,p.SaleCost,slip.Quantity,slip.Amount FROM tblstockissuanceslip slip " +
        "INNER JOIN tblprowareinventory pi ON slip.inventoryID_FK = pi.inventoryID " +
        "INNER JOIN tblprowareproducts p ON pi.ItemID_FK = p.ItemID "+
        "WHERE slip.SIP_NO = ""+topass+";
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryProducts,con.connection))
        {
            --remove line below
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?slipno", slip_no);
            --remove line above

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            using (MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                mda.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
```

What really happens is, the parameter cannot retrieve the value which you are trying to pass. Just a tip, try learning how to use stored procedures and functions in SQL, they will make your life more peaceful.

Comment: DON'T concatenate query strings! Using parameters is the [correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i).

Comment: agreed, but I dont know how to code in c#, what I would suggest to him would be stored procedures.

Comment: @MatSnow its still returning all the items in the table, its like its ignoring the `where` clause

Comment: It is ignoring the where clause when you use your parameter, if you use mine, it will get the parameter, but be careful, my answer is susceptible for a SQLi attack, but it gives you a lead on what you have to do.